# creating a loopback in powershell until variable is met

Tags: powershell-4.0

i assume i have made a basic mistake here but i am trying to make a simple code that randomly generates 2 numbers no larger than 10 and adds together. i want the final product to be an exact size as this will slot into a auto password generator i am coding. i have rest of code fine but have been unable to get $c to be anything other than 8, nor will it loop like this. if i just take the function rando and run separate it works every time but often overshoots my ideal size.

what do i need to do to keep this looping until my variables end up at the Goldilocks number?

```
Function (rando)
{
$a = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$b = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$c = $a+$b
}

Function Test
{
if($c -ne 8)
{
rando
}
else
{
    Write-Host $c
}
}
Write-Host $c
```

Comment: i realize i said it only generates 8, when i was testing i had it set as 12 and forgot i scaled back to 8 before posting but the issue is still same, any number i put in it always sticks on 8. so i def have a bug causing the variables to stick.

Answer (score 0):

whoops i fixed it; i forgot nested variables needed to be declared prior. this is my working code:

```
$a = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$b = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$c = $a+$b

Function blue
{
$a = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$b = Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1 
$c = $a+$b
Test
}

Function Test
{
if($c -ne 12)
{
blue
}
else
{
 Write-Host $c
}
}

Test
```